# How do i display the variables that were chosen?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    
        int r, value;
        int v1[6];
        cout<<"How many colours?: ";
        cin>>r;
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            cout<<"\nColours:";
            cout<<"\n(1) Pink";
            cout<<"\n(2) Blue";
            cout<<"\n(3) Green";
            cout<<"\n(4) Yellow";
            cout<<"\n(5) Red";
            cout<<"\n(6) Orange\n";
            cout<<"\n Pick a colour: ";
            cin>>v1[6];
            cout<<"How many?: ";
            cin>>value; 
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            
        if(v1[6] == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Pink";
        }
        else if(v1[6] == 2)
        {
            
            cout<<"Blue";
        }
        else if(v1[6] == 3)
        {
            
            cout<<"Green";
        }
        else if(v1[6] == 4)
        {
            
            cout<<"Yellow";
        }
        else if(v1[6] == 5)
        {
            
            cout<<"Red";
        }
        else if(v1[6] == 6)
        {
            
            cout<<"Orange";
        }
        
        }
    


        return 0;

    }
```

The above is my codes. The problem I am facing now is that whenever i pick more than 2 colours and when displaying them, it only displays the last choice of mine twice. For example, when i pick 2 colours or more, for example, Pink and Blue, instead of outputting Pink Blue, it outputs Blue Blue (twice) or when i pick 3 colours, Pink Blue Yellow, it outputs Yellow Yellow Yellow. How can i fix this?

Comment: first you should know that your code has access violation. meaning that you are trying to access v1[6] which is not in array size(v1[6] -> meaning your array has size of 7). another note every time you execute loop you are write given input to v1[6] which is result in override previous loop input(i mean in every loop you lost previous loop input).

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on any of the solutions proposed below?

Answer (score 0):

`v1[6]` is an access outside the bounds of the array; it's Undefined Behavior. You probably want `v1[i]`.

I strongly recommend going away from C arrays. Use `std::array` for fixed size or `std::vector` for dynamic size.

As a side note `cin>>value;` looks suspicious. You override `value` at each iteration i.e. you lose all the values except the last one.